# Moving files with the same name from different folders into folders with the same name as the files?

Tags: batch-file, rename

I have 13 folders each with 36 tiles.

The folders are named:

```
NAMEFOLDER_60min
NAMEFOLDER_75min
...
NAMEFOLDER_240min
```

The tiles are named according to their coordinates

```
tile_x001_y001.tif to tile_x001_y006.tif
tile_x002_y001.tif to tile_x002_x006.tif
...
tile_x006_y001.tif to tile_x006_y006.tif
```

At this moment, the pictures are grouped in folders by time points but I would like to group them by coordinates. For example moving every `tile_x001_y001.tif` from all folders to a new folder named `tile_x001_y001`, but then for all pictures. In order to prevent overwriting, I believe the tiles have to be renamed as eg. in folder "tile_x001_y001": tile_x001_y001_60min.tif, tile_x001_y001_75min.tif,..., tile_x001_y001_240min.tif

I tried making new folders and tried some scripts I found online for moving/copying the pictures to the corresponding folder but it fails because the script I tried uses one folder containing all pictures but I have multiple folders and when I move/copy more than one picture with the same name to the new folder, it overwrites it.

```
@echo off
for /l %%y in (1,1,6) do for /l %%x in (1,1,6) do (md tile_x00%%x_y00%%y)

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%A in (*.tif) do (
   echo file found  %%A
   for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do set fname=%%~nB
   for /f "delims=" %%C in ("%%A") do set fextn=%%~xC
   for /f "tokens=* delims=_" %%D in ("!fname!") do set folname=%%D
   echo folder name !folname!
   if not exist "!folname!" (
      echo Folder !folname! does not exist, creating
      md "!folname!"
   ) else (
      echo Folder !folname! exists
   )
   echo Moving file %%A to folder !folname!
   move "%%A" "!folname!"
   )
echo Finished
pause
```

Comment: how do you want same-named files to be renamed?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and put all relevant information there rather than posting comments! May the folder names contain `_` on their own before the `_*min` suffix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT : Added the renaming of each copied file.

Here's a suggestion in Powershell

Replace the paths according to your needs.  I also made it copy instead of moving the files, if all goes well you can just cleanup the source afterwards...

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\source" -Recurse -Directory

foreach ($folder in $folders) {

    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\source\$($folder.name)" -File

    $atfn = $folder.Name
    $atfn = $atfn.Substring(11)

    foreach ($file in $files) {

        $folderName = $file.Name
        $folderName = $folderName.Substring(0,$folderName.Length-4)

        if (!(Test-Path -Path D:\destination\$($folderName))) {

            Write-Host "Directory does not exist - Creating Directory"
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "D:\destination" -Name $folderName
            Write-Host "Copying file..."
            Copy-Item -Path "D:\source\$($folder.name)\$($file.Name)" -Destination "D:\destination\$($folderName)" -Force
            Rename-Item -Path "D:\destination\$($folderName)\$($file.Name)" -NewName "$($folderName)_$($atfn).tif"

        }

        else {

            Write-Host "Copying file..."
            Copy-Item -Path "D:\source\$($folder.name)\$($file.name)" -Destination "D:\destination\$($folderName)" -Force
            Rename-Item -Path "D:\destination\$($folderName)\$($file.Name)" -NewName "$($folderName)_$($atfn).tif"

        }

    }

}
```